# spring 4 not validate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value="/app/home/refernece",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processReference(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("refernceForm") @Validated @Valid ReferenceForm referenceForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

     if(!bindingResult.hasErrors()){
         boolean emailExists = customerservice.customerWithEmailExists(referenceForm.getRefernceMail());
         if (!emailExists) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("refernceMail", "registrationform.valid.email.exists");
        }            

     }
     System.out.print(referenceForm.getRefernceName());
     if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        //logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Form Errors.");
        //model.addAttribute("BindingResult",bindingResult);
        //model.addAttribute("refernceForm", new ReferenceForm());
    return "view/app/refernce";
    }
     return "redirect:/home/systemschein";

 }
```

- This my handler method.
- I add 2 validator to this controller but its not validating?

Comment: how to debug the validator

Comment: First off all 1 of the annotations is enough, secondly why and what should it validate...

Answer (score 0):

Your ModelAttribute name may have a typo - it says 'refernceForm' when maybe it should say 'referenceForm'. If you post the code for the ReferenceForm class we can also check what it should be validating.

Comment: how to add validator to controller I use this

Comment: `@InitBinder
 private void initrefernceBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.setValidator(contactFormValidator);
  binder.setValidator(refernceFromValidator);
 }`

Comment: Solved Use 2 @Initinder("modelattribute")